# Failure: no .proto target files found while running buf breaking even when the proto file exist

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-go

I am trying to test [breaking change](https://docs.buf.build/breaking/usage#limit-to-specific-files) by running `buf breaking` command like this

```
buf breaking --against '../.git#branch=master' --path grpc/path/to/protoFile.proto --error-format=json
```

Upon running this I get an error which says

`Failure: no .proto target files found`

The confusion is that I am providing the absolute path of my `.proto` file but still I get `no files found` error. What am I missing here?.

Comment: Probably better raised as an issue on Buf's [repo](https://github.com/bufbuild/buf/issues). Could it be that `grpc/path/to` is not present in the Git repo? What if you run `buf lint` instead with that path?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see with my own recent testing, this error occurs when you're trying to do `buf breaking` against a branch that doesn't yet have the proto files in it. Were there existing proto files in master when you attempted to target it with `buf breaking`?

Another issue you might have is that you need to make sure you've informed `buf breaking` of where your `buf.yaml` is for the git repo. If it's not in the root of your repository, you'll need to add the `subdir` option to your `--against` argument to ensure imports are resolved correctly as shown in this example on their documentation: https://docs.buf.build/tutorials/getting-started-with-buf-cli#run-buf-breaking

Assuming your `buf.yaml` was in `grpc` rather than the root of the project, you'd need to modify your command to be:

```
buf breaking --against '../.git#branch=master,subdir=grpc' --path grpc/path/to/protoFile.proto --error-format=json
```